# How to replace slash with questionmark in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slash

Somehow i could nowhere find a solution how to convert

```
https://example.com/api/command
```

to

```
https://example.com/api?command
```

in a .htaccess-file. Anyone a quick solution to this? It should only internally redirect.

Here what does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)?$ api?$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Kindly do add your htaccess file in your question for better understanding of your question thank you.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/([0-9]+)?$ api?$1 [NC,QSA]

Comment: When phrasing such a question it would be helpful to explain what "does not work" actually means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your htaccess file in following way, written and tested with shown samples. Also please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(api)/(.*)/? $1?$2 [NC,L]
```